# Visual Studio 2017 eating disk space in Local AppData folder

Tags: visual-studio, diskspace, appdata

After running TreeSize Free, I found that Visual Studio is gobbling up disk space in C:\Users\{Me}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio folder... specifically in the WebTools\ChromeUserDataXXX\Default\Extensions.

Does anybody know what these are for, why they're so big (>11gb) and if I can safely remove them or change some settings so not so much is stored?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something wrong is with the Screencastify extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screencastify-screen-vide/mmeijimgabbpbgpdklnllpncmdofkcpn) in WebTools. If you do not need WebTools, remove it manually or using VS installer.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't occur to me to google that mmeijim... I assumed it was a randomly generated string.  But it does point right to screencastify.  The strange thing is there is no visual studio webtool for that, however in the past I did have that chrome extension enabled.  I deleted it and all the related files from my screenshot, and all seems to still be working fine.